# storing email in PST file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to set up some older emails as pst files on my hard drive rather than keeping them on the server CanI transfer existing outlook files o do this, and how can I later access the individual emails if I want to?

Comment: *set up some older emails as pst files*...What does that mean? Do you want to *move* email into a PST file?

Comment: It’s a reasonable question to ask, but being there are several drawbacks to doing this, the first question that should be asked is why, or should, you be doing this? Email storage is not typically an issue nowadays.

Comment: Is this a company-owned computer connecting to a corporate-managed Exchange server? In many cases, PST creation is actually blocked on domain computers so that people cannot save files this way, and your local IT should be contacted to find a creative alternative appropriate within your organization.

Comment: @Appleoddity Office 365 limits your mailbox to 50 GB. I have a client that routinely has to move data elsewhere because of it, though I agree with you in general.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator there are archive solutions for Office 365 too for this very reason.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator then enable the archive mailbox, it is another 50Gb to 100Gb for this exact purpose, or purchase more storage. Anybody using that much email storage is begging for special circumstances, but certainly not using PST files.

Comment: My point (for the benefit of the OP's question) is that there are cases where moving email out of the main mailbox is a legitimate need. *How* that gets done is situation-driven.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator 50 GB limit isn’t a Office 365 limit, I say that, due to the 99 GB mailbox I have at work.

Comment: @Ramhound What you're saying is accurate, but the default limit depends on the subscription level. Enterprise E3 is where the 100GB boxes start to come from. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#StorageLimits

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Outlook Auto-Archive feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Archive-older-items-automatically-25f44f07-9b80-4107-841c-41dc38296667) is for: it can automatically backup your old emails into a local PST file.